# rails: how to create record in other Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, create-table

So i need to create two Records

one is appointment, and the other one is answer.

```
def create
  @check_up_appointment = CheckUpAppointment.new(appointment_params)
  @check_up_appointment = current_user.check_up_appointments.build(appointment_params)
  companion = Companion.find(@check_up_appointment.companion_id)
  reserved_at = Time.zone.parse(appointment_params[:reserved_at])

  @check_up_answer = CheckUpAnswer.new(
    user: current_user,
    companion_id: @check_up_appointment.companion_id,
    check_up_appointment_id: @check_up_appointment.id,
    basic_info: [],
    health_info: [],
    previous_illness: [],
    recent_info: [],
  )

  @check_up_appointment.save
  result = @check_up_appointment,  @check_up_answer
  render json: {result: result}
end
```

so i need to create answers when the appointment is made, but now the code doesn't works at all

so where do i have to fix??

and second thing is when answer is made it should have empty array

how can I figure this out

Comment: solved i placed the code wrong place

Answer (score 0):

When you call `current_user.check_up_appointments.build`, an instance of
`CheckUpAppointment` is created. This doesn't mean that it is inserted in the database.

At this point in the execution of the code, the object `@check_up_appointment` does not have an `id`, this field is only set for objects that are persisted in the database. You can check this by inserting `puts @check_up_appointment.id.nil?` in the 4 line of this snippet. It'll output `true`

When you call `@check_up_appointment.save`, the record wil be validated and in the positive case inserted to the database. After the `save` call the `id` field will be set.

Now you try to set `check_up_appointment_id: @check_up_appointment.id,` which is most likely the reason for the code not working (I guess that a validation doesn't pass, but some log output would help a lot).

Try this:

```
def create
  @check_up_appointment = current_user.check_up_appointments.build(appointment_params)
  companion = Companion.find(@check_up_appointment.companion_id)
  reserved_at = Time.zone.parse(appointment_params[:reserved_at])
  
  @check_up_appointment.save
  
  @check_up_answer = CheckUpAnswer.new(
    user: current_user,
    companion_id: @check_up_appointment.companion_id,
    check_up_appointment_id: @check_up_appointment.id,
    basic_info: [],
    health_info: [],
    previous_illness: [],
    recent_info: [],
  )


  result = [@check_up_appointment,  @check_up_answer]
  render json: {result: result}
end
```

**Another thing:**

The first line of the 2 lines below is 100% redundant and you can remove it.

```
  @check_up_appointment = CheckUpAppointment.new(appointment_params)
  @check_up_appointment = current_user.check_up_appointments.build(appointment_params)
```

**Also:**
I changed a bit in the last 2 lines.